# How to pass data between AppDelegate and SecondViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, pass-data

I've got `@property NSDate` instance and it get time in method `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`
.

I've got `ViewController` and `SecondController` connected to `Storyboard` so in code in AppDelegate Implementation block i haven't any ViewController and SecondViewController instance. Method `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
 only returns YES.

The problem is: I must to pass time from `@property NSDate` instance to `SecondViewController` which is displayed when application is become active, but i don't know how can i check if `SecondViewController` is displayed after application comes from background.

I know that i can use AppDelegate:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

And then get his `NSDate @property`, but how can i check when i have to get this data?

Which method of `ViewController` should i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `SecondViewController`'s view to always have the current date value when it appears, get it from the data model (in this case AppDelegate) during `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: problem is when i add `NSLog` in `SecondViewController` `viewWillAppar:` method i see any results.. This view is displayed when i click home and when i back is displayed too so `viewWillAppear` isn't called.

Comment: That's odd.  What causes `SecondViewController` to be used?  If it's a segue, what triggers the segue...code or some user action?

Comment: Yeah, i've got `ViewController` and `UITableView`. When i select `Cell` then by `Modal Segue` application display `SecondViewController`. And when this `SecondViewController` is displayed i want to lock iDevice, but when i do this then `AppDelegate` get date when i do this and when application become active i want to get data from `AppDelegate` and edit it in `SecondViewController`. Any `viewWill...` or `viewDid...` isn't working with `SecondViewController` : /

Comment: In that case, have your `SecondViewController` listen for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification.  You should get called when the device is unlocked.